# Django ModelChoice Field Conditional ForeignKey

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I've surfed most of the afternoon and have been at this particular quandry for a while.

I am trying to figure out how to essentially present a foreign key as a dropdown choice if the user has driven that type of car.  For example purposes and to keep this as easy as possible...

Let's say I have  a`Cars`, `Manufacturers` and a `UserProfile` model.

I have a model for `Cars` as so...

```
class Cars(models.Model):

    car_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)    
    class = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer,null=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='car_manufacturer')
```

I have a model for `Manufacturers` as so...

```
class Manufacturers(models.Model):

        manu_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

Then I have a `UserProfile` model....

```
class Userprofile(models.Model):

   user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   user_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)    
   car_owned = models.ForeignKey(Car,null=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='car_owned')
```

All good so far...

I have a view where I am listing all of the `Manufacturers` and this works fine as well.  It shows all of the manufacturers that I would expect in the form view below.

```
class ManufacturerForm(forms.Form):

    dropdown = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Manufacturer.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ManufacturerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['dropdown'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'choices1'
        self.fields['dropdown'].empty_label = ''
```

I'm using the FORMVIEW below to display the form...

```
class ManufacturerView(LoginRequiredMixin,FormView):
    form_class = ManufacturerForm
    template_name = 'Directory/HTMLNAME.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ManufacturerView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        manufacturer = form.cleaned_data['dropdown']
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("NAME:manufacturer",kwargs={'pk':manufacturer.pk}))
```

This all works fine.  However, I can't figure out how to limit the manufacturer dropdown to only the cars the user has driven.  I'm trying to essentially limit the dropdown display to only the manufacturers that are pertinent to the cars the user has owned based on their profile.  I've researched reverse look ups and have also tried something similar to what is outlined below to solve my problem...

```
class ManufacturerForm(forms.Form):

    dropdown = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Manufacturer.objects.filter(car_manufacturer=1)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ManufacturerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['dropdown'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'choices1'
        self.fields['dropdown'].empty_label = ''
```

But this obviously only gives me record 1 for the `Manufacturer` model.  I am trying to figure out how to display only the records that are relevant to an individual user based on their car_owned data.  I can list all of the manufacturers and then just display the records that are relevant in a `ListView`, but I am trying to limit the dropdown to only where there are relevant records in a `ListView`.  Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed just couple of points:
1) Pass `UserProfile` as `kwargs['user']`:

```
kwargs['user'] = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
```

2) Add `user` parameter in form's `__init__` signature and override `dropdown.queryset` there:

```
class ManufacturerForm(forms.Form):
    dropdown = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Manufacturer.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ManufacturerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['dropdown'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'choices1'
        self.fields['dropdown'].empty_label = ''
        self.fields['dropdown'].queryset = Manufacturer.objects.filter(car_manufacturer__car_owned=user)
```

Also I would like to recommend to rewrite your `Car - User` relationship to ManyToMany. If I understand correctly your message, User can have multiple cars:

> limit the dropdown display to only the manufacturers that are
>   pertinent to the car**s** the user **has owned**

Also if I understand correctly, you want to track cars that user used to have (but doesn't have anymore).
If you rewrite `Car - User` relationship, then you won't probably have any reason to keep `UserProfile` model only to hold additional `username`. If so, your `models.py` should look like this:

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)


class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    klass = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='car_manufacturer')
    owners = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Ownership')


class Ownership(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)   # True if user owns the car at the moment
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was the part that was tripping me up...Manufacturer.objects.filter(car_manufacturer__car_owned=user)..all day I might add!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think it all hinges on your order and relationships between models, perhaps try adding in a `ManyToMany` relation between `Manufacturer` and `Car`, so one manufacturer can make many cars:

class Manufacturer(models.Model):

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
car = models.ManyToManyField(Car)
```

Then it may be a case of doing something such as:

```
qs = Manufacturer.objects.all(car=user.car_owned)

dropdown = forms.ModelChoiceField(qs)
```

And in your `views.py` file:

```
form = ManufacturerForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
```

(You may need to look up if the above is valid, as I'm not sure if Forms can have the request object passed in).

Disclaimer: I see you're using a `class` based view...so I may need to tweak the above.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.  I am playing with your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work.  There is a problem with the keyword portion of the qs = Manufacturer.objects.all.  If I put anything other than a hardcoded car=1 or car=2, or car=3 it errors out.

Comment: Hi Steve - not to worry, what is the error you’re receiving?

Comment: Along the lines of not defined.  The keyword syntax seems to be causing errors.

Comment: Is it on the line with form = ManufacturerForm ... ?

Comment: I’ve also renamed your class, as a class represents one object, so none pluralised. You instantiate multiple instances of the same object, so User, Car, Manufacturer etc Ignore my pedantic nature and maybe change anywhere where I have used Manufacturer to your class defined as Manufacturers. :)

Comment: I've tried several iterations but nothing works.  I am trying to essentially figure out a reverse look up on the filter.  I can do dropdown = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Manufacturer.objects.filter(car_manufacturer=1) as stated above, but that's as far as I get.

Comment: Are you able to pass in the user contest in your view?

Comment: I am.  If I do something like..        qs = Manufacturer.objects.filter(id__in=user.userprofile.manufacturer.all()) but I'm not able to figure out how to get the car reference incorporated into the equation.

Comment: You need to pass in your request.used object for the currently logged in user. I have also added an extra ManyToMany field in the Car model, that’s how you tie it all together.